# onclick and identity of an object

Tags: javascript, onclick, prototype

I hope this still makes sense. I don't have the code with me but I wonder how I can do this. The problem is at " `onclick=\"thatThing.doSmthg();\"` ".

It results in "thatThing is not defined".

Thanks!

```
var oneThing = new Thing();

letsDoSmthg(oneThing);

letsDoSmthg(thatThing){
    document.getElementById("fezok").innerHTML+="<input type=\"button\" value=\"Do smthg\" onclick=\"thatThing.doSmthg();\">";
}

function Thing(){
    this.variable1=0;
}
Thing.prototype={
    doSmthg: function(){
        this.variable1=1534;
    },
```

Comment: You should create actual DOM elements and use `addEventListener()` to pass a function with a closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use strings to create HTML. Use elements.

```
var letsDoSmthg = function(thatThing) {
    var button = document.createElement('input');
    button.type = 'button';
    button.onclick = function() {
        thatThing.doSmthg();
    };

    document.getElementById("fezok").appendChild(button);
};
```

Comment: what if I don't want to use dom elements?

Comment: @user2090805 then don't do web development?

Comment: I switched to dom elements... But I meant out of curiosity, how should I have done it if dom didn't exist?

Comment: @user2090805 if the DOM didn't exist then the HTML would not exist either and there would be no question

Comment: Ok nvm mister knows it all